# height calculation is not working properly

Tags: html, css

i have a div and i give the style for this div is

my problem is

```css
.scrollgrid
{
   
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden; 

height:calc(69% - (40px + 40PX));

    
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollgrid">12345678901223567890012345678901234578900
   123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012123456789012235678900123456789012345789003456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900 </div>
```

when i resize the page this div is not resizing .
my requirement is 
1. when i resize the page the end of the scrollbar is should seenable

Comment: So what's the problem? I can see the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have your x and your y back to front.

```
.scrollgrid
{   
 overflow-y:hidden;
 overflow-x:scroll; 
}
```

Comment: I assumed OP wants the scrollbar to look larger since the header of the question relates to the height calculation problem, but your guess looks much more sensible.

Comment: Haha. Yes, I figured between the two of us @Cheslab @ aswathy might have his / her answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate 69% of `body` if `body` does't have a height. 
Add this:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.scrollgrid {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: calc(69% - (40px + 40PX));
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollgrid">12345678901223567890012345678901234578900 123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012123456789012235678900123456789012345789003456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900123456789012235678900123456789012345789001234567890122356789001234567890123457890012345678901223567890012345678901234578900</div>
```